# Plot one graph with many variables on x and y axis using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my data.

```
Localities  Variable1  Variable2  Variable3   Variable4
SNP              5        1          2            0
BNP              1        2          4            2
MWC              0        3          1            3
```

I already use `reshape2` package to combine the data. But I am clueless what script should I use. I want to put Localities in x axis, and variables in y axis. Do I need to melt two things here? As for variables I need to put it in a different colour as well. I want to put piloint graph.

This is what I have tried, before plotting graph.

```
Cv=c("Variables 1", "Variables 2", "Variables 3", "Variables 4"), ID=variables)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `reshape2` to `melt` your data, it will look like

```
> library(reshape2)
> melt(df)
Using Localities as id variables
   Localities  variable value
1         SNP Variable1     5
2         BNP Variable1     1
3         MWC Variable1     0
4         SNP Variable2     1
5         BNP Variable2     2
6         MWC Variable2     3
7         SNP Variable3     2
8         BNP Variable3     4
9         MWC Variable3     1
10        SNP Variable4     0
11        BNP Variable4     2
12        MWC Variable4     3
```

Using these column names, you can use `ggplot2` to plot whatever you like, as you have all your values in one column, so you can plot them against an axis. You can use the `variable` column to color, if you like. A very simple plot, with your specifications, using dodging to show overlapping points:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(aes(Localities, value, colour = variable), data = melt(df)) + 
    geom_point(position = position_dodge(.1))
```

[image: scatterplot]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It helps me a lot

Comment: I'm glad it's helpful! Please consider upvoting and/or accepting it.